# How can i add a dropdownlist in the register model

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

// this code thows up an error that there is no viewdata item of type //IEnumerable for Companytype

//current code in RegisterModel

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompName { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Type")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompTypeList { get; set; }



    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Total number of Branches")]
    [Range(1,10,ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1}")]
    public int TotalBranches { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }






}
```

//current code in view

```
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompName)
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompTypeList)
            @Html.DropDownList("Companytype","-select one-")
        </li>

        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalBranches)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalBranches)
        </li>




        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
```

//AccountController Register
    private DefaultDBEntities3 db = new DefaultDBEntities3();

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.CompTypeList = new SelectList( "Companytype");
        return View();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

your assistance will be much appreciated

Comment: //DBName DefaultDB
//DBTable CoAdd
//DBvar CoID(Identity) and Companytype

insert into CoAdd values('Telecommunications')
insert into CoAdd values('Automotive')
insert into CoAdd values('Government')
insert into CoAdd values('Banking'

Comment: you don't add dropdownlists to Models. they are created in Views. I think what you're asking is, what kind of Entity will scaffold a dropdownlist. That's something you should research. This forum is not for that kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

A select list item is an invalid parameter for the html.dropdownlist helper. It is looking for a list. Store only the data inside the viewbag and create the select list inside the view as such:

//Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
ViewBag.CompTypeList = db.Companytype.OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList();
return View();
}
```

//View

```
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyType", new SelectList(ViewBag.CompTypeList, "Id", "Name"))
```

This will properly render your drop down list inside the view and eliminate your error. Id is the value field for your list, Name is the field to be displayed. Hope this helps.